# Manage Site Content and Structure in SharePoint Online missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site, site-settings

The option Manage Site Content and Structure is missing in SharePoint Online since a few weeks. 
Normally the option was visible under: Site Settings > Site Administration, but it isn't there anymore. Does anyone have an idea where we can find it now?

We can access the page through _layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx behind the URL, but this is a workaround.

The site collection feature 'SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure' is activated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from Sept 2018, this feature has been deprecated in SPO and replaced with new File move and copy functionality in the modern views

[image]

Reference - [SharePoint Site Content and Structure (In Office 365)](https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/148/entryid/800/sharepoint-site-content-structure-deprecated-in-office-365.aspx)

Admin message center ID - [MC143382](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/home?switchtomodern=true#/MessageCenter?id=MC143382)

Comment: Thank you, that explains why the option is no longer present. We will take a look at how we will deal with this. For now the URL is still working :)