# How to move files SharePoint Online with Classic Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-settings, classic-experience

As described in this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251825/manage-site-content-and-structure-in-sharepoint-online-missing) the option Manage Site Content and Structure is missing in SharePoint Online and, although there is a solution for Modern Experience, I can't see any for Classic Experience.

Does a solution exist?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use send to.
[image]

2.Use file explorer.

Open both source and target document libraries and select ‘File Explorer’ in the ribbon. This will open up an explorer view for each library. You can drag and drop files between the two document libraries.

3.Workflow or flow.

4.PowerShell.

[Move a file between document libraries using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-move-files-using-powershell.html)

5.3rd Party Product.

[ShareGate](https://sharegate.com/sharepoint-migration?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkKOxzbH-7AIVxK2WCh16CQVHEAAYASAAEgLUuPD_BwE)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And so you confirm that, in classic experience, there is no SPO function to move a file as simply as clicking a button "Move".

The solutions you described are too complicated for my needs: explaining how to move a file to not skilled people.

The first two are better but require too work: "Send to" requires to delete the original file (and if you have more than one file you have to remember to remove all the original files, wherever they are) and "File Explorer" is only available in Internet Explorer (as long as Microsoft support it). Anyway thanks.

Comment: Yes, in the classic experience, there is no SPO function to move a file as simply as clicking a button "Move" in the modern experience. If the answer is helpful, you could mark it as answer.